# Can we hide & show buttons using appcast xml file parameter

Tags: android, xml, flutter, dart

I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader) plugin very useful to me. But I want to show & hide 'Ignore' & 'Later' buttons using `appcast xml` file parameter.

Because when some time needs to allow users to use the app without update that time we want to show ignore **&** later buttons & sometimes need to update forcefully that time we want to display only update button.

So i want to handle this using `appcast xml`. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

got a solution from @larryaasen who owns this plugin. In your Appcast XML file use sparkle:criticalUpdate like this to disable the Ignore and Later buttons.

```
<item>
    <title>Version 2.0</title>
    <description>desc</description>
    <pubDate>Sat, 26 Jul 2014 15:20:11 +0000</pubDate>
    <enclosure url="http://localhost:1337/Sparkle_Test_App.zip" sparkle:version="2.0" />
    <sparkle:tags> <sparkle:criticalUpdate /> </sparkle:tags> 
</item>
```